# "Filter" a php array based in winner/loser

Tags: php

I am trying to create a 'table' with winners/losers from a match; for this I receive the data from an API in json and decode it to an array, this isn't a problem per-se, is just Im curious if is possible to do this, but in a 'better way':

```
$table = array("winner" => array(), "loser" => array());
foreach($matchinfo as $team){
    if($team->Win_Status == "Winner"){ array_push($table["winner"], $team); }
    if($team->Win_Status == "Loser"){ array_push($table["loser"], $team); }
}
```

Maybe more 'clean' or with better 'perfomance'.

Comment: This question is better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not much cleaner I think.

```
foreach($matchinfo as $team) {
    $table[$team->Win_status][] = $team;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it a little more readable (not that the original isn't), you can use `array_filter`:

```
function only_winners($team) {
  $team->Win_Status == 'Winner';
}

function only_losers($team) {
  $team->Win_Status == 'Loser';
}

$winners = array_filter($matchinfo, 'only_winners');
$losers = array_filter($matchinfo, 'only_losers');
```

Comment: yes, he said "clean" **or** "performance" :) . I think this is cleaner and more understandable than the previous "slick" answer